# How to efficiently extract lists of values from a dictionary when searching by these values in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, extract

I have a large log file which after parsing into a dictionary which takes a form of:

```
data = {id: {"datetime": datetime, "string": string}}
```

where:

```
datetime: str
string: str
id: int
```

(a dict with nested dicts)
for example:

```
data = {
0: {"datetime": "03.04.2019", "string":"abc"},
1: {"datetime": "04.04.2019", "string":"abc"},
2: {"datetime": "05.04.2019", "string":"abc"},
3: {"datetime": "05.04.2019", "string":"xyz"},
4: {"datetime": "06.04.2019", "string":"abc"},
5: {"datetime": "06.04.2019", "string":"xyz"},
6: {"datetime": "07.04.2019", "string":"abc"}
}
```

As you can see neither datetime, nor string are unique in each of the nested dictionaries. However with each following id, following datetimes are greater or equal to the previous datetimes.

I want to create a function that extracts only the inner dicts between specific datetimes inclusively. For example my function:

```
def extract(start_datetime, end_datetime, data)
    ...
```

for parameters:

```
extract("05.04.2019", "06.04.2019", data)
```

should return:

```
{
2: {"datetime": "05.04.2019", "string":"abc"},
3: {"datetime": "05.04.2019", "string":"xyz"},
4: {"datetime": "06.04.2019", "string":"abc"},
5: {"datetime": "06.04.2019", "string":"xyz"}
}
```

I was thinking about implementing myself a binary search function that would  go through the inner datetime values and extract only the inner dicts which match the search criteria, however I am a lazy programmer, and I am looking for a more pythonic solution. Because this is a large dataset, efficiency is very important, so the function should be as fast as possible.

Comment: If `{datetime, value}` isn't supposed to be a set, please fix

Comment: SO is not a free coding, tutorial, or research site. Please put in the effort to define what you want to do, then do it, and only post a question when you run into problems that way.

Comment: If you want to use binary search then you should have a list, not a dict. The binary search algorithm is implemented by the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module (if `bisect` had a `key` parameters, which does not [yet](https://bugs.python.org/issue4356), it would be a bit simpler, but as it stands you would probably need something like a list of tuples `('YYYY.MM.DD', <id>)`).

Answer (score 0):

Another possiblity would be :

```
import time

def extract(start, end, data): 
    output_dict= {}
    for key, val in data.items(): 
        if (isinstance(val, dict) 
            and time.strftime(val.get('datetime')) >= time.strftime(start) 
            and time.strftime(val.get('datetime')) <= time.strftime(end)): 
            output_dict[key] = val
    return output_dict

extract("05.04.2019", "06.04.2019", data)
```

Output :

```
{2: {'datetime': '05.04.2019', 'string': 'abc'},
 3: {'datetime': '05.04.2019', 'string': 'xyz'},
 4: {'datetime': '06.04.2019', 'string': 'abc'},
 5: {'datetime': '06.04.2019', 'string': 'xyz'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of one liner

```
import time

data = {
    0: {"datetime": "03.04.2019", "string": "abc"},
    1: {"datetime": "04.04.2019", "string": "abc"},
    2: {"datetime": "05.04.2019", "string": "abc"},
    3: {"datetime": "05.04.2019", "string": "xyz"},
    4: {"datetime": "06.04.2019", "string": "abc"},
    5: {"datetime": "06.04.2019", "string": "xyz"},
    6: {"datetime": "07.04.2019", "string": "abc"}
}

data_in_time_range = [entry for entry in data.values() if
                      time.strftime(entry['datetime']) >= time.strftime('05.04.2019') and time.strftime(
                          entry['datetime']) <= time.strftime('06.04.2019')]
print(data_in_time_range)
```

output:

```
[{'datetime': '05.04.2019', 'string': 'abc'}, {'datetime': '05.04.2019', 'string': 'xyz'}, {'datetime': '06.04.2019', 'string': 'abc'}, {'datetime': '06.04.2019', 'string': 'xyz'}]
```